# How to find location of a pinned item using MapKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I used MapKit's localsearch feature to generate annotation pins of whatever was typed into a search bar. I am now having trouble finding the address of those pinned locations. this is my code for the local search

```
func performSearch() {


    matchingItems.removeAll()

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text;

    request.region = attractionsMap.region;

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse!,
        error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
        } else {
            println("Matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.attractionsMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is my viewForAnnotation method:

```
extension AttractionsVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if(annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil;
    }
    let reuseId = "pin";
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView;
    if(pinView == nil) {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId);
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true;
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true;
    }
    var moreInfoButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as! UIButton;
    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = moreInfoButton;
    return pinView;
}
```

I would now like to be able to display the address on the annotation. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you implement mapVIew(_, viewForAnnotation:) in MKMapViewDelegate ?

Comment: So the pins is added to MapView, and you can't find it right ?

Comment: I can find it, but I want to be able to know the address of the pinned location. For example, if i type in coffee, i get around 10 matches and are then pinned onto the map. When i click the pin, it shows the name of the place, but i want to get the location of that pin in order to show it on a detailed viewcontroller.

Comment: You seem confused about what you want. "Address" is one thing, "location" is another. Which do you want?

Comment: Sorry, I wish to find the location as in coordinates

Comment: Modified my answer to include the location as in coordinates as well as the address as in postal address, since I can't figure out what you want (can _you_ figure it out?).

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand what it is you want. Sometimes you ask about the address, sometimes you ask about the location.

**The location is the latitude and longitude**

It is the annotation's `coordinate` property.

**The address is the human postal address**

When you called

```
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.startWithCompletionHandler( // ...
```

...you got back MKMapItems:

```
for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
```

Inside each MKMapItem was a placemark (an MKPlacemark, the MKMapItem's `placemark` property). Inside each placemark was the address information — an MKPlacemark is a CLPlacemark, so consult the CLPlacemark document for how to extract the address info.

Well, you appended each MKMapItem to an array:

```
matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
```

That's where the MKMapItems are, unless you've thrown them away; so that's where the address information is.

Comment: Yes, but how do i get the location for each specific pin? Would I have to iterate through that array or...?

Comment: You are a programmer, you think of something. You are the one who is making the pins. If you know you are going to want to associate the address with the pin later, plan ahead! Associate them somehow!